# unexpected token using function within function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below function is above my render function, what's wrong with that? it seems doesn't allow me to put function within function.

```
onSelected(i){

    this.state.active = [];
    this.state.active[i] = true;

    generateRangeFromIndex(index,steps=20){
        return [index*steps, index*steps+steps]
    }

    this.setState({
        active: this.state.active,
        showHandler: true,
        selectedRange: generateRangeFromIndex(i)
    });

}
```

Comment: You can't have a method directly inside a method... it must be inside an object literal, class, etc. Define it using a function declaration.

Comment: Post the rest of your code please

Answer (score 0):

```
onSelected(i){

    this.state.active = [];
    this.state.active[i] = true;

    let t  = this; 

    this.setState({
        active: this.state.active,
        showHandler: true,
        selectedRange: t.generateRangeFromIndex(i)
    });

}
generateRangeFromIndex(index,steps=20){
    return [index*steps, index*steps+steps]
}
```